# How do I replicate a nested for loop with mapply?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, mapply

I would like to vectorize the creation of a list in R, but can only get what I want with a nested for loop. I've included a vastly simplified version of my problem for reproducibility. Can someone help me to modify or replace my mapply function?

Desired functionality:

```
my_list <- list()
A <- c("one", "two", "three", "four")
B <- c("left", "right")
for (a in A) {
    for (b in B) {
        my_list <- c(my_list, paste(a, b))
    }
}
print(my_list)
```

output (edited white space for brevity):

```
[[1]] [1] "one left"
[[2]] [1] "one right"
[[3]] [1] "two left"
[[4]] [1] "two right"
[[5]] [1] "three left"
[[6]] [1] "three right"
[[7]] [1] "four left"
[[8]] [1] "four right"
```

My attempt to vectorize this:

```
combinate <- function(a, b) {
    return(paste(a, b))
}
mapply(combinate, a=A, b=B, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

output:

```
$one   [1] "one left"
$two   [1] "two right"
$three [1] "three left"
$four  [1] "four right"
```

I'm not concerned about labels; I'm concerned about getting all eight results from looping over both lists. I have found documentation that mapply is doing exactly what it is supposed to by pairing the first items from both lists, then the second items from both lists, etc. repeating shorter lists. But after much searching, I can't find what must be there, a way to pair all list items combinatorically like the nested for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do with `expand.grid` and `paste`

```
v1 <- do.call(paste, expand.grid(A, B))
```

---

Or with `outer`

```
v1 <- c(outer(A, B, paste))
```

---

If these needs to be in a `list`

```
as.list(v1)
```

---

Checking with the OP's output

```
identical(as.list( c(t(outer(A, B, paste)))), my_list)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I'm learning the hard way that while these do exactly what I had asked in the question, they don't function quite the same as the for-loop. The paste function is not being called 8 times, each with different variables, but being passed two lists or arrays of 8 items. The outer function expects that the paste function (or whatever custom function you provide) can handle that correctly. Or correct me if I still misunderstand. :)

Comment: @mightypile  In the `outer` the `FUN` argument is `paste`.  What `outer` does is to get the combination of elements of each vector and by specifying `paste` as `FUN`, it is doing the pasting